# Nginx ingress : Host based routing on TCP port

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress

Usage of the same TCP port for Rabbitmq 5672 and transfer requests to different `namespaces/rabbitmq_service` based on the host-based routing.

What works:

```yaml
chart: nginx-git/ingress-nginx
version: 3.32.0
values:
  - tcp:
      5672: "cust1namespace/rabbitmq:5672"
```

Block reflected in nginx.conf:

```
server {
    preread_by_lua_block {
        ngx.var.proxy_upstream_name="tcp-cust1namespace-services-rabbitmq-5672";
    }
    listen                  :5672;
    proxy_pass              upstream_balancer;
}
```

Note: this will transfer all the requests coming to port 5672 to `cust1namespace/rabbitmq:5672`, irrespective of the client domain name and we want host-based routing based on domain name.

What is expected:

```
chart: nginx-git/ingress-nginx
version: 3.32.0
values:
  - tcp:
      cust1domainname:5672: "cust1namespace/rabbitmq:5672"
      cust2domainname:5672: "cust2namespace/rabbitmq:5672"
```

Error:

```
Failed to render chart: exit status 1: Error: unable to build kubernetes objects from release manifest: error validating "": error validating data: [ValidationError(Service.spec.ports[3].port): invalid type for io.k8s.api.core.v1.ServicePort.port: got "string", expected "integer", ValidationError(Service.spec.ports[4].port): invalid type for io.k8s.api.core.v1.ServicePort.port: got "string", expected "integer"]
```

The final nginx.conf should look like:

```
server {
    preread_by_lua_block {
        ngx.var.proxy_upstream_name="tcp-cust1namespace-services-rabbitmq-5672";
    }
    listen                  cust1domainname:5672;
    proxy_pass              upstream_balancer;
}
    
server {
    preread_by_lua_block {
        ngx.var.proxy_upstream_name="tcp-cust2namespace-services-rabbitmq-5672";
    }
    listen                  cust2domainname:5672;
    proxy_pass              upstream_balancer;
}
```

Comment: What protocol is used for `rabbitmq` messages which are sent to ingress? I see there are [some options](https://www.rabbitmq.com/protocols.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### A bit of theory

Approach you're trying to implement is not possible due to network protocols implementation and difference between them.

`TCP` protocol works on transport layer, it has source and destination IPs and ports, it does **not** have any hosts information within. In turn `HTTP` protocol works on application layer which seats on top of the `TCP` and it does have information about host where this request is intended to be sent.

Please get familiar with [OSI model and protocols which works on these levels](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/806-4075/ipov-10/index.html). This will help to avoid any confusion why this works this way and no other.

Also there's a [good answer on quora about difference between HTTP and TCP protocols](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-HTTP-protocol-and-TCP-protocol/answer/Daniel-Miller-7?srid=nZLo).

### Answer

At this point you have two options:

1. Use ingress to work on application layer and let it direct traffic to services based on hosts which are presented in `request body`. All traffic should go through ingress endpoint (usually it's loadbalancer which is exposed outside of the cluster).

Please find examples with

- [two paths and services behind them](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#simple-fanout)
- [two different hosts and services behind them](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#name-based-virtual-hosting)

2. Use ingress to work on transport layer and expose separate TCP ports for each service/customer. In this case traffic will be passed through ingress directly to services.

Based on your example it will look like:

```
chart: nginx-git/ingress-nginx
    version: 3.32.0
    values:
    - tcp:
        5672: "cust1namespace/rabbitmq:5672" # port 5672 for customer 1
        5673: "cust2namespace/rabbitmq:5672" # port 5673 for customer 2
        ...
```